# How to configure the sslContextParameters in the camel spring xml

Tags: apache, apache-camel

```
<camel:sslContextParameters id="sslContextParameters">
    <camel:keyManagers keyPassword="changeit">
        <camel:keyStore type="JKS" resource="C:\keystore.jks"
            password="changeit" />
    </camel:keyManagers>
    <camel:trustManagers>
        <camel:keyStore type="JKS" resource="C:\keystore.jks"
            password="changeit" />
    </camel:trustManagers>
</camel:sslContextParameters>
```

When I tried too load the resource like in the above xml , I still get SSL handshake exception. Please help me out the same how to set the camel http connection with the SSL parameters reference added to it , so that I can hit any secured link without any SSL handshake exceptions

Comment: What kind of camel component are you using?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs, you apply the SSL context parameters against an option for the `http4` component.

```
<to uri="https4://127.0.0.1/mail/?sslContextParametersRef=sslContextParameters"/>
```